# UICollectionView load more data

Tags: ios, cell, uicollectionview

I want to fetch more data from server if the last cell will display, but UICollectionView don't have method -willDisplayCell like UITableview. So I have no idea about this situation, can somebody tell me what should I do , thanks!

Comment: Hi Billwang, can you please share sample of a project how you achieve this with UICollectionView?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply implement the fetching operation inside -

```
  (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and check for the condition

```
 if(indexPath.row==your_array.count-1).
```

Comment: @vaibhav_15 and how could I add a uiactivity indicator in in bottom/footer of collection view?

Answer (score 15):

you can also use the scrollview delegate since uicollectionview inherits from uiscrollview , just implement the uiscrollview delegate method :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

and do something like :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
      //LOAD MORE
      // you can also add a isLoading bool value for better dealing :D
   }
}
```

Comment: @HirenPanchal, Great.