# Detecting the last collection view cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a collection view that loads 30 objects from my server. I need to know when the final cell goes across the screen so that I can refresh the data with 30 more objects. How do I do that in a collection view? Can I detect which cell is on the screen with the following?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
}
```

Comment: You could, using `scrollView.contentOffset`.  You could also check the `indexPath` in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, (for example, `if (indexPath.row % 30 == 0) { }`)

Comment: Interesting. I like the if (indexPath.row % 30 == 0) { }. Can you expand a bit more on that?

Comment: Please check the below link..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587570/uicollectionview-load-more-data

Comment: @KevinPuntney It just tests whether the current row is evenly divisible by 30.  So the code would trigger on cells 30, 60, 90, 120, etc.  You could call a method that starts a request.  (Just make sure to check if you've done it already, since it could fire multiple times from the user scrolling up and down.)

Comment: Thanks. That's really interesting stuff!